# How To Improve Speed Send Mail With Larg Attachments Using Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, performance, attachment, email-attachments, nodemailer

Sorry my English is not good, I hope everyone understands.
I have api send mail using nodemailer.
If you choose a file >10mb, the process of sending mail takes 100 seconds. How can it be faster?

Comment: Many email providers will outright refuse messages bigger than a certain size, typically around ~10MB, so be careful when doing this.

Comment: I use gmail service, can attachment 25mb. But i send mail with attchment ~10mb take 100s to finish process. How to improve that?